# Is there a R function to have the difference between n-1 row

Tags: r

I have a dataset below

```
    A  B
1   1 11
2   2 13
3   3 15
4   4 17
5   5 18
6   6 20
7   7 25
8   8 30
9   9 40
10 10 80
```

I need to create a new column called C and have difference between 2 and 11, 3 and 13 and so on. The final output should be

```
    A  B   C
1   1 11   NA
2   2 13   9
3   3 15   10 
4   4 17   11
5   5 18   12
6   6 20   12
7   7 25   13
8   8 30   17
9   9 40   21
10 10 80   30
```

Comment: That function is `lag`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in base R -

```
df$C <- c(NA, df$B[-nrow(df)]) - df$A
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `shift` function from `data.table` package-

**Code**

```
> setDT(data)[ , C := shift(B) - A]    
> data
     A  B  C
 1:  1 11 NA
 2:  2 13  9
 3:  3 15 10
 4:  4 17 11
 5:  5 18 12
 6:  6 20 12
 7:  7 25 13
 8:  8 30 17
 9:  9 40 21
10: 10 80 30
```

**Input Data-**

```
data <- read.table(text = "   A  B
   1 11
   2 13
   3 15
   4 17
   5 18
   6 20
   7 25
   8 30
   9 40
  10 80",header=T)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most intuitive way is to use `lag()` as suggested by @camille.

```r
data %>% mutate(C=lag(B)-A)

    A  B  C
1   1 11 NA
2   2 13  9
3   3 15 10
4   4 17 11
5   5 18 12
6   6 20 12
7   7 25 13
8   8 30 17
9   9 40 21
10 10 80 30
```